# dropdown-menu with a second class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

All dropdown-menu have margin declared, but i want one of them to have different margin, so i have added a second class:

html:

```
<li class="dropdown"> 
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-target="#"  role="button" aria-haspopup="true" href="#">Matrimoni</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="matrimoni.html" role="menuitem">Panoramica</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="format.html" role="menuitem">Format</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="ambienti.html" role="menuitem">Ambienti</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="patner.html" role="menuitem">Patner</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>

                <li class="dropdown" role="menu">   
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-target="#"  role="button" aria-haspopup="true" href="#">Eventi</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu menueventi">
                        <li role="presentation"><a  href="eventiprivati.html" role="menuitem">Privati</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="eventibuisness.html" role="menuitem">Buisness</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="eventispeciali.html" role="menuitem">Eventi Speciali</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

css:

```
 @media (max-width: 980px) {    
   .nav > li > a {  
      width:88px; 
   }
   ul .dropdown-menu {
      margin-left:-31px;
   }
 }

@media (max-width: 862px) {
   .nav > li > a {
      width:auto; 
      padding: 3px 3px;
   }

   .menueventi{
      margin-left:-47px;
   }
 }
```

but the menueventi does not work, on the browser this class does not appear in the html code.

any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just change the margin of .dropdown-menu at (max-width: 862px) instead of adding a new class?

Comment: because i want dropdownmenu menuevent with a different margin of other dropdown-menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
```

link:-http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html

Comment: sorry can you explain?

Comment: What i'll explain?

Comment: i have not understand your solution